# How do you prove $\nexists$ a normal subgroup H < $\Re$ such that $\Re$/H is isomorphic to $Z$2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**Problem:**
Prove that there does not exist a normal subgroup H < R such that R/H is isomorphic to Z2. Where R is the group of real numbers and addition, and Z2 is the group of integers modulo 2.

**Hint:** If a + H maps to 1 $\in$ Z2 under such isomorphism, where does a/2 + H map?

**What I know:**
{a + H : a $\in$ R} is the quotient group R/H and so I'm mapping those elements of R/H to Z2 in this hypothetical isomorphism.

Why am I supposed to consider a/2 + H though? Or how do I know what it maps to? I suppose if it is equal to 1, the map would not be bijective and so it would not be an isomorphism. But I don't know how I should be concluding where a/2 + H goes.

Edit: I wish I could accept multiple answers

Comment: mathjab please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to know which element $\frac{a}{2}+H$ maps to, just to think what would happen if such isomorphism exists.
Suppose there is a isomorphism $f$. Your hypothesis is that $f(a+H) = 1$. Now $\frac{a}{2}+H + \frac{a}{2}+H = a+H$, then $f(\frac{a}{2}+H + \frac{a}{2}+H) = f(a+H)=1$, but $f(\frac{a}{2}+H + \frac{a}{2}+H) = f(\frac{a}{2}+H) +f(\frac{a}{2}+H) = 0$ since $0+0=1+1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! This explanation makes a lot of sense. I want to some day build my intuition to better see relations like that.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose such an isomorphism existed. Then, if $a/2$ is mapped to $1$, then we have $a = a/2 + a/2$ being mapped to $1 + 1 = 0$ (group homomorphisms preserve operation). If $a/2$ mapped to $0$, then we again have $a$ mapped to $0$.

Comment: Hence a contradiction with our initial assumption that a maps to 1. I feel stupid! Thank you for the help.